# Fancybox only working sometimes without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, dom, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox so users can click on image thumbnails and see larger images.

The problem I'm having is that it doesn't always work when the page loads. I'll click on the thumbnails and the Fancybox doesn't show the larger images. If I refresh the page however, it works just fine. The content is generated dynamically so I wonder if I need to refresh the DOM?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'fade', // openEffect / closeEffect / nextEffect / prevEffect 
                closeEffect : 'fade', // Animation effect ('elastic', 'fade' or 'none') for each transition type
                nextEffect  : 'fade', // String; Default value: 'fade', 'fade', 'elastic', 'elastic'
                prevEffect  : 'fade',
                openSpeed   : '1000', // openSpeed / closeSpeed / nextSpeed / prevSpeed     
                closeSpeed  : '1000', // The time it takes (in ms, or "slow", "normal", "fast") to complete transition
                nextSpeed   : '1000', // Integer; Default value: 250
                prevSpeed   : '1000',
                padding     : 3
            });
        });
    </script>

<a class='fancybox' rel='gallery' href='".$data['photo'][$x]."'><img src='".$data['photo'][$y]."' style='margin-right: 2.5px; margin-left: 2.5px; vertical-align: top;'></a>
```

When it's not working and I click on the thumbnail, here's the error that I get...

`TypeError: a[0] is undefined` in jquery.fancybox.pack.js on line 15.

Here's how I'm calling Fancybox, maybe that's the problem?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>`

I don't care which version of fancybox I' using as long as I get functionality here as well as on another page where I have a Fancybox that shows when the page is loaded.

Comment: do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Check the console log when the error appears and show us. Apparently there is no error.

Comment: any chance you can share a link? BTW, all integer and Boolean values go without quotes so `closeSpeed  : '1000'` should be `closeSpeed  : 1000` etc.

Comment: @darshanags Just added the error. Took a while to get it to not work right

Comment: @JustinWhite can you use `jquery.fancybox.js` instead of 'jquery.fancybox.pack.js' and post the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple images at same page with same class instead of calling like above you can use

```
$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
     openEffect  : 'fade', // openEffect / closeEffect / nextEffect / prevEffect 
            closeEffect : 'fade', // Animation effect ('elastic', 'fade' or 'none') for each transition type
            nextEffect  : 'fade', // String; Default value: 'fade', 'fade', 'elastic', 'elastic'
            prevEffect  : 'fade',
            openSpeed   : '1000', // openSpeed / closeSpeed / nextSpeed / prevSpeed     
            closeSpeed  : '1000', // The time it takes (in ms, or "slow", "normal", "fast") to complete transition
            nextSpeed   : '1000', // Integer; Default value: 250
            prevSpeed   : '1000',
            padding     : 3
});
```